# How do you build a .jar that contains external .jar dependencies?

Tags: java, jdbc, gradle

I'm using the Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 to connect to SQL Server. In Eclipse I have added the .jar file to the class path of my project ( C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc41.jar).

I've added this .jar to a folder called lib in my project and am trying to have this .jar added as part of my .jar:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

dependencies {
    compile files('lib/sqljdbc41.jar')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

However, sqljdbc41.jar is not included in my .jar. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a (application) distribution to package your libraries and application jar in a folder: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Alternatively you can use a plugin like https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow to create a self-contained uberjar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chromanoid. I was able to solve the problem two ways. First I placed the sqljdbc41.jar in a new folder called lib in my project. Solution 1 was to create an application distribution:

```
apply plugin:'application'
apply plugin: 'java'

mainClassName = "main.java.application.Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

dependencies {
    runtime files('lib/sqljdbc41.jar')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

}
```

You can then create a distribution using the distZip task. Solution 2 was to create a fat jar.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

configurations {
    provided
    compile.extendsFrom provided
}

dependencies {
    runtime files('lib/sqljdbc41.jar')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

}

jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    from {
        (configurations.runtime - configurations.provided).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
}
```

and use the build task.